# copy constructor for a class with pointer to a user defined type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have seen many examples of copy constructor for classes with member variables as pointer to int or char. Can someone advise on the right way of writing a copy constructor for a class A with a member ptrB which is a pointer to user defined class B please.

Is this correct:

```
class A {
    private:
      B *ptrB;
    public:
      A() { ptrB = new B; }
      A(const A& other);
      ~A();
}

A::A(const A& other)
{
  ptrB = new B;
  *(ptrB) = *(other.ptrB);
}
```

and If ptrB was defined like this:

```
shared_ptr<B> ptrB;
```

then this?

```
A::A(const A& other)
{
  ptrB(new B);
  *(ptrB) = *(other.ptrB);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of your copy constructor and destructor and it should work fine on its own as a smart pointer.

Comment: @chris That will not work fine at all with the first example of a raw pointer.

Comment: @chris i'd like to know answer to the first part of my question too. i.e. with naked pointer.

Comment: I see no problem with your raw pointer copy constructor assuming B is trivial or has an `operator=` to handle the assignment correctly. You would be better off with a copy constructor on B because then this`A::A(const A& other)` becomes `A::A(const A& other):ptrB(new B(other.ptrB))` and no code is required in the constructor body.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I think this is what I was missing.

Comment: Not a problem. If you haven't seen this already, read up on the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok as in the comments, here is the answer:

in the case of naked pointer my code above works but this is a better version as uses initialization list and performs better:

```
A::A(const A& other):ptrB(new B(other.ptrB)) {}
```

and in the case of shared_ptr, I don't need copy constructor and destructor.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `A::A(const A& other):ptrB(new B(*(other.ptrB))) {}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the post with "deep-copy" I assume you want the copy constructor to do that. The default copy constructor generated using shared_ptr does **not** deep copy.

I would suggest that there are two general forms for copying a pointer-like member.

```
Deep(const Deep& other): ptr(new T(*other.ptr)) {}
```

and

```
Shallow(const Shallow& other) = default;
```

Note, a shallow copy like that won't work for a unique_ptr. By design, unique_ptr prevents that.

Here is an example of each, showing the difference. Nb, using the raw version in practice could easily lead to a memory leak. The important point is that after the shallow copy, modifying the copy modifies the original.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename TPtr>
struct Deep
{
    TPtr ptr;

    Deep() : ptr(new T) {}

    T get() const { return *ptr; }
    void set(T t) { *ptr = t; }

    Deep(const Deep& other): ptr(new T(*other.ptr)) {}
};

template<typename T, typename TPtr>
struct Shallow
{
    TPtr ptr;

    Shallow() : ptr(new T) {}

    T get() const { return *ptr; }
    void set(T t) { *ptr = t; }

    Shallow(const Shallow& other) = default;
};

template<typename T>
using raw_ptr = T*;

template<typename T>
void test(const T& a1)
{
    auto a2 = a1;
    a2.set(a2.get() + 1);
    std::cout << a1.get() << " " << a2.get() << std::endl;  
}

using std::shared_ptr;

int main()
{
    Deep<int, raw_ptr<int> > rawDeep;
    rawDeep.set(1);
    test(rawDeep);

    Deep<int, shared_ptr<int> > sharedDeep;
    sharedDeep.set(1);
    test(sharedDeep);

    Shallow<int, raw_ptr<int> > rawShallow;
    rawShallow.set(1);
    test(rawShallow);

    Shallow<int, shared_ptr<int> > sharedShallow;
    sharedShallow.set(1);
    test(sharedShallow);
}
```

http://ideone.com/NltfUO